# Как привязать рекламный баннер к локализации приложения?

Tags: java, android

Компания startAD mobi отклонило мое приложение по причине:
Баннер StartAD.mobi должен отображаться на том же языке, что и локализация приложения (в русской версии приложения баннер должен быть на русском, в английской версии приложения соответственно на английском). В вашем приложении при английской локализации показываются русскоязычные баннеры.

Сейчас код выглядит так:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

// мой id
this.sadView = new SADView(this, "99999999999999999999999");

LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.myleaner);

layout.addView(this.sadView);
this.sadView.loadAd(SADView.LANGUAGE_RU);
```

Вопрос: как реализовать привязку рекламного баннера к локализации приложения?

После реализации предложенного метода:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        // мой id
        this.sadView = new SADView(this, "99999999999999999999");

        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myleaner);

        layout.addView(this.sadView);


        //this.sadView.loadAd(SADView.LANGUAGE_RU);
public static  Locale getSystemLocale(){
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                return Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration().getLocales().get(0);
            } else {
                return Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration().locale;
            }
        }
        switch (getSystemLocale().getLanguage()) {
            case "ru":
                sadView.loadAd(SADView.LANGUAGE_RU);
                break;
            case "en":
                sadView.loadAd(SADView.LANGUAGE_EN);
                break;
        }
    }
```

---

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        // мой id
        this.sadView = new SADView(this, "59e49c13e229e670008b4569");

        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myleaner);

        layout.addView(this.sadView);
public static  Locale getSystemLocale(){
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                return Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration().getLocales().get(0);
            } else {
                return Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration().locale;
            }
        }
}
            switch (getSystemLocale().getLanguage()) {
                    case "ru":
                    sadView.loadAd(SADView.LANGUAGE_RU);
                    break;
                    case "en":
                    sadView.loadAd(SADView.LANGUAGE_EN);
                    break;
                    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно получить текущую локаль:

```
public static Locale getSystemLocale() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        return Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration().getLocales().get(0);
    } else {
        return Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration().locale;
    }
}
```

и далее от нее крутиться:

```
switch (getSystemLocale().getLanguage()) {
    case "ru":
        sadView.loadAd(SADView.LANGUAGE_RU);
        break;
    case "en":
        sadView.loadAd(SADView.LANGUAGE_EN);
        break;
}
```

*Это все будет работать в том случае, если локаль приложения зависит от локали системы.*

Comment: Error:(52, 16) error: illegal start of expression
Error:(52, 9) error: illegal start of expression
Error:(52, 29) error: ';' expected
Error:(52, 47) error: ';' expected
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.  Не пойму где чего-то не хватает

Comment: @АрменМхитарян, Без кода я тоже не пойму.

Comment: Добавил код в исходное сообщение

Comment: @АрменМхитарян, Блок `switch-case` нужно поместить в конец метода `onCreate(...)`.

Comment: Тоже самое. Если кликнуть два раза по ошибке, курсор перемещает на строчку: public static  Locale getSystemLocale(){  . Может в ней что-то не так?

Comment: @АрменМхитарян, Очевидно, ее нужно вынести вне метода `onCreate(...)`.

Comment: Так и делаю, ничего не изменилось.

Comment: @АрменМхитарян, Покажите код.

Comment: Извиняюсь, понял ошибку. Большое спасибо